# Share data between android application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider

I am working on android application and I want to share sign in information of user between my two applications signed with same certificate and it needs to be robust and secure. I know about two approaches.

1. **Sharing data using Intent**
2. **Develop custom provider with set of permission**
3. **Using SharedPreferences(Which I don't like personally)**

Is there any other approach that I can use which is more secure and stable as user session needs to be secure?

**UPDATE :**

My backend is already there and I can't make any changes to it. I have to accommodate this change on UI side by sharing session between application in most secure way. One more thing I want it in way that user can sign in to any of my application and session will be shared.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use an external database?

Comment: @cricket_007 Can you share any example if it's available that how can I share data between application using it and how secure it is?

Comment: I would give Parse.com as an example, but that is going out of service soon. It is a mBaaS, or Mobile Backend as a Service. I hear Kinvey is an alternative, but I never used it. You could also startup your own MySQL server if you really wanted.

Comment: [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/pricing.html) is another alternative since it appears Kinvey doesn't provide User authentication in the free tier.

Comment: @cricket_007 My backend is already there and I can't make any changes to it. I have to accommodate this change on UI side by sharing session between application in most secure way.

Comment: Can you be a lot more specific as to "most secure" because the "most secure" version would not be storing any confidential information at all.

Comment: @cricket_007 Session id of user is very sensitive as if it goes into someone else's hand they can manipulate with user data.